# How do I pass an intent from an activity to a class extending LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I have to pass an Intent value (String) to my class extending LinearLayout. I had tried

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Chat_Layout.class);
in.putExtra("Rid", RequestID);
```

by passing the value to the linearlayout class, but can't retrieve the value since it shows undefined error in getIntent().

```
ReqID = getIntent().getStringExtra("Rid");
```

Comment: Can't you have a public method in your extended LinearLayout class to pass whatever you want?

Comment: Yes I do have a public method when I call it  shows, The method getIntent() is undefined for the type

Comment: Rather than passing the data through Intent, you could just pass the value by myCustomLinearLayout.setRefID(referenceId); ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `getIntent()` in a `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout` is a derived class of that). In your extended `LinearLayout`, you need something like this:

```
public void setReqId(String rid) {
    this.rid = rid;
}
```

And from your activity call it with

```
extendedLinearLayout.setReqId(getIntent().getStringExtra("Rid");
```

You can do this from your activity when you have a reference to your extended `LinearLayout`. You can get a reference to it like so in your activity (assuming your class is called `ExtendedLinearLayout`

```
ExtendedLinearLayout extendedLinearLayout =
    (ExtendedLinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.extended_linear_layout);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have to pass value from Activity class to the LinearLayout class.

Comment: @kapil updated my answer on how to do this in an `Activity`